# How to upgrade Celery from AMQP to RPC?

Tags: python, celery

How do you upgrade a Celery 4 configuration, that uses the AMQP backend, to Celery 5, which has dropped this support and now requires you to use the RPC backend?

After upgrading to Celery 5.1.2, I received the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.backends.amqp'
```

which I expected. However, it's unclear how the rpc backend replaces this.

My CELERY_BROKER_URL looks like `amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/myvhost`, which accesses RabbitMQ.

I tried changing this to `rpc://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/myvhost`, and I changed my `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` to `rpc://`, but that just gives me a different error:

```
KeyError: 'No such transport: rpc'
```

While there's a ton of [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/internals/reference/celery.backends.rpc.html), it's unclear what I'm doing wrong. How do you upgrade Celery from amqp to rpc?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it worked then I did:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://whateveryouhadhere'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://whateveryouhadhere'
```

I don't know why but I hope it helps someone.